# INSERT INTO table with Foreign Key from Form

Tags: ms-access, vba, foreign-keys, insert-into

I am trying to create a Form that is used to manually enter data in certain scenarios. Most data is input from CSV files which is working fine. I have 4 tables, `Part` , `Assembly` , `MachineOrder` , and `Job`. I was able to write code for entering into the base table, `Part`, from the Form no problem. The issue now is entering data into the `Assembly` and `MachineOrder` tables where the Parts are being referenced by their `PID` autonumber field and the Assemblies are being referenced by their `AID` autonumbered field. I have tried many different kinds of methods to perform this of which you can see a bit of in my commented out code. What is there is what I believe to be my closest to correct code thus far with the error now being that Access asks me for the parameter value of `rPID` even though it is finding the value in the `Dlookup` function fine. I'm assuming the same is true for the `rAID` section as well.

Otherwise I'm getting errors of Key Violations when using the `INSERT` then `UPDATE` method you see commented out.

The form is called `HOTEntry`

Any advice on what my problem may be is greatly appreciated, I'm a student and this is my first time trying to use what I've learned in a professional application so any and all constructive criticism is wanted! Apologies if this is a rather specific question but I could really use the help on this since I've been working on it for two days to no avail...

My code:

```
Sub HOTParts2()

Dim rPID As Integer  
Dim rAID As Integer  
Dim dbs As DAO.Database  
Dim sqlstr1 As String  
Dim sqlstr2 As String  
Dim sqlstr3 As String  
Dim sqlstr4 As String  

Set dbs = CurrentDb  

'sqlstr1 = "INSERT INTO Assembly ( PID, ModelNum, ModelRev, ModelDescription ) " _  
'        & "SELECT (PID,Forms!HOTEntry!txtHotModel, Forms!HOTEntry!txtHotRev, Forms!HOTEntry!txtHotDes)" _
'        & "FROM Part " _
'        & "WHERE Part.PartName = Forms!HOTEntry!txtPartName AND Part.Config = Forms!HOTEntry!txtConfigEntry AND Part.Rev = Forms!HOTEntry!txtRevEntry"
sqlstr1 = "INSERT INTO Assembly ( ModelNum, ModelRev, ModelDescription,PID ) " _
        & "VALUES (Forms!HOTEntry!txtHotModel, Forms!HOTEntry!txtHotRev, Forms!HOTEntry!txtHotDes," & "rPID" & ");"
'
'sqlstr2 = "UPDATE Assembly " _
'        & "SET PID =" & rPID & " " _
'        & "WHERE Assembly.ModelNum = Forms!HOTEntry!txtHotModel And Assembly.ModelDescription = Forms!HOTEntry!txtHotDes And Assembly.ModelRev = Forms!HOTEntry!txtHotRev;"
'
'sqlstr3 = "INSERT INTO MachineOrder ( AID, Serial, CustName ) " _
'        & "SELECT (AID,Forms!HOTEntry!txtHotSerial, Forms!HOTEntry!txtHotCust)" _
'        & "FROM Assembly" _
'        & "WHERE Assembly.Model=Forms!HOTEntry!txtHotModel And ModelDescription= Forms!HOTEntry!txtHotDes And ModelRev = Forms!HOTEntry!txtHotRev; "
sqlstr3 = "INSERT INTO MachineOrder (Serial, CustName, AID ) " _
        & "VALUES (Forms!HOTEntry!txtHotSerial, Forms!HOTEntry!txtHotCust," & "rAID" & ");"
'
'sqlstr4 = "UPDATE MachineOrder " _
'        & "SET AID =" & rAID & " " _
'        & "WHERE AID IS NULL;"

rPID = DLookup("PID", "Part", "PartName = " & "'" & Forms!HOTEntry!txtPartName & "'" & " And " & "Config = " & "'" & Forms!HOTEntry!txtConfigEntry & "'" & " And " & "Rev = " & "'" & Forms!HOTEntry!txtRevEntry & "'")

DoCmd.RunSQL sqlstr1
'DoCmd.RunSQL sqlstr2

rAID = DLookup("AID", "Assembly", "ModelNum = " & "'" & Forms!HOTEntry!txtHotModel & "'" & " And " & "ModelDescription = " & "'" & Forms!HOTEntry!txtHotDes & "'" & " And " & "ModelRev = " & "'" & Forms!HOTEntry!txtHotRev & "'")

DoCmd.RunSQL sqlstr3
'DoCmd.RunSQL sqlstr4


End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if you want to use the looked up rPID and rAID in a query, you need to do more than just set them in VBA. You can either manually fill them in in your SQL statement, use a parameter and a QueryDef and fill in the parameter in your QueryDef, or put the DLookUp inside your SQL statement.
Going with the first approach here, only unquoted rPID in your initial statement, and put it after rPID was set.:

```
rPID = DLookup("PID", "Part", "PartName = " & "'" & Forms!HOTEntry!txtPartName & "'" & " And " & "Config = " & "'" & Forms!HOTEntry!txtConfigEntry & "'" & " And " & "Rev = " & "'" & Forms!HOTEntry!txtRevEntry & "'")
sqlstr1 = "INSERT INTO Assembly ( ModelNum, ModelRev, ModelDescription,PID ) " _
    & "VALUES (Forms!HOTEntry!txtHotModel, Forms!HOTEntry!txtHotRev, Forms!HOTEntry!txtHotDes," & rPID & ");"
DoCmd.RunSQL sqlstr1
```

Comment: Wow, I thought I had already tried that but I think having the sqlstr statements after the variable was set really did the trick. Thank you!